# Is it possible to monitor the data usage for an specific WIFI network in Android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, usagestatsmanager, networkstatsmanager

I want to monitor the data usage for an specific WIFI network using an Android device. Looking into the API's documentation, I've found the following classes [NetworkStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html) and [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html), but none of them seems to help me. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Comment: Probably what you want is just get the name of current Wifi and compare (?) data usage. Maybe you just need to get the SSID of Wifi then compare over time with the UsageStatsManager.

Comment: I use a free app called Data Usage Monitor Ver 1.13.1403 by Lufesu Inc
Fantastic little app, shows data used by SSID and Apps, Day Week Month etc. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andcreate.app.trafficmonitor&hl=en